# Bluetooth default connection interval in iOS 5.x / iOS 6

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I implemented data exchange between a BLE chip and an iOS device.
To temporarily speed up the data transfer, the connection interval on the chip side is dynamically modified to:

```
- min interval : 20 ms
- max interval: 40 ms
- slave latency : 0
- timeout : 300 * 10ms
```

**First test with an iOS 5.1 device**

On iOS 5.1 the change of this parameter take 6 seconds. The result interval connection is over 40 ms (44 ms).
Before connection interval change, the "default" interval connection seems to be ~100 ms.

**Same test with an iOS 6 device**

On iOS 6.0 the change of this parameter take 1 second only. The result interval connection is over 40 ms (48ms).
Before connection interval change, the "default" interval connection seems to be ~28ms.

**Here are my questions:**

1. Can somebody confirm these "defaults" value for the connection interval depending on the iOS version?
2. Is there a way to handle the change of the connection interval value on iOS 5.1 in less than 6 seconds? If yes, how?
3. Why the asked value for the connection interval does not seem to be correctly changed (44 > 40 on iOS 5.1, 48 > 40 on iOS 6)?

Comment: What was the protocol you used to change the connection interval? I assume that the BLE chip you mentioned is a peripheral?

Comment: Yes the BLE chip is used as peripheral (iOS device is master in this case). What do you mean by "protocol" ?

Comment: Are you sending low level commands? If so, what is it?